# Appium No such element Webview automation

Tags: java, appium, appium-ios

I have a webview that needs to be automated, my code is like this, but the element could not be found. “no such element: Unable to locate element:”

I’m verifying the elements with chrome inspect. Do you have any thoughts? Thank you very much for your help.

[image]